# CocoaPod Spec dynamically identify platform

Tags: ios, macos, bash, cocoapods

I want to use two different `prepare_command` for iOS and macOSX but `CocoaPods` doesn't support command like this

> spec.ios.prepare_command

Is there any way to know in `PodSpec` file that `pod` is being built for `iOS` or `macOSX`??